# Trying to rotate a bitmap without success

Tags: android, bitmap, xamarin, xamarin.android

I`m editing a bitmap to optimize it for an OCR scan. One of the things I need to do is to rotate the image 270 degrees. I'm using the following code:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.PostRotate (270);
canvas.DrawBitmap(alteredBitmap, matrix, paint);
```

Apparently, this does not work for me. Can someone point out where I am wrong?
The bitmap comes from a `byte[]`.

Comment: define "does not work".  Is it crashing?  Does it not display anything?  Does it display the bitmap, but without the rotation?

Comment: I haven't worked on xamarin but i have rotated images in C#. In C# i needed to recalculate the stride for the rotated image as the width of the image changes if you rotate it 90/270 degrees

Comment: @Jason does not work = does not rotate the image

Comment: @wandering-warrior can you provide a little snipet of code?

Comment: `current_height = pixel_arr_rotated.GetLength(0); 
current_width = pixel_arr_rotated.GetLength(1);
stride = current_width * bytes_perpixel;
while (stride % 4 != 0)             
          stride++; `

Here pixel_arr_rotated is a 2d array or matrix of all the pixels after rotating the original matrix. Stride is calculated as shown

Comment: @BogdanConstantin  dude did you try the stride method?
Can you try another overload for the DrawBitmap mentioned here.
It needs a color array instead of matrix..  Other wise i guess you'd have to create a new bitmap instead of only drawing.

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Graphics.Canvas.DrawBitmap/p/System.Int32[]/System.Int32/System.Int32/System.Single/System.Single/System.Int32/System.Int32/System.Boolean/Android.Graphics.Paint/

Comment: I don't understand how to use that overload. Sorry for my noobness :) If you can help me a bit that'll be awesome :)

Comment: @BogdanConstantin  Does it work if you give it 180 degrees?

Comment: first i have to get it written.. and i don`t have any idea how to

Answer (score 0):

This method has always worked for me

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
   //myBitmap is the bitmap which is to be rotated
    matrix.postRotate(rotateDegree);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);//Rotated Bitmap
```

Well if you have this bitmap generated from a url , go ahead and use this function

```
public Bitmap decodeBitmap(File f) {

    try {
        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        //The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 490;

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale = 1;
        while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale *= 2;

        //Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that if i create another one i exceed the memory

Comment: Are you getting this bitmap from a file , if yes then you need to decode it properly to reduce its size in order to avoid memory leaks

Comment: can you provide documentation or a snipet of code ?

Comment: you are resizing it. i need the pictures to be as big as posible so the OCR with Tesseract has the most chances to read the image.

Comment: You could fiddle with REQUIRED_SIZE variable and see what fits your situation

Answer (score 0):

This is the snippet of code I use to rotate a `byte[]` in my projects. It receives and returns a `byte[]`, but by removing the last 5 lines of code it'll return a `Bitmap` instead. It works wonders:

```
public async Task<byte[]> RotateImage(byte[] source, int rotation)
{
    //This is optional, use it to reduce your images a little
    var options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.InSampleSize = 2;

    var bitmap = await BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArrayAsync(source, 0, source.Length, options);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.PostRotate(rotation);
    var rotated = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, matrix, true);

    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    await rotated.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);
    var result = stream.ToArray();

    await stream.FlushAsync();
    return result;
}
```

All awaitable calls have non-async counterparts, so this can be converted to run in a blocking way without major issues. Just beware that removing the `options` variable might cause `OutOfMemoryException`, so make sure you know what you're doing before removing.